# SwiftUI - New comments are duplicating when posted

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

In my comments feature, I've made it so each post has its own set of comments, and every time the "comments" button is pressed, the comments have to reload to so no other post's comments carry over.

However, when I'm posting a new comment, the view duplicates the comments. But when I reload the comments view, the duplicated comments reduce to one, which is the way it should be. Only one comment document is created in Firebase, so the duplication issue is in my app, not Firebase.

I've demonstrated this here, as I think this is the best way to show the problem: https://giphy.com/gifs/ZpYBXPnhcjlAz33Hb9

In this GIF, you'll see the new comment creates 5 versions of itself. Then, when I close the view and reload it, that same comment only shows one instance, which is how I want it.

Unsure how to solve this. I've thought of completely closing and reopening the view when a comment is posted, but I don't think thats the most efficient way to do things.

*CommentsView.swift*

```
@ObservedObject var commentsData: CommentsViewModel
```

```
 HStack(){
                TextField("Type Something...", text: $commentsData.commentTxt)
                    .foregroundColor(.white)
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .textFieldStyle(PlainTextFieldStyle())
                    .background(Color.white.opacity(0.06))
                    .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                    .cornerRadius(12)

                Button(action: {
                        commentsData.comment(id: post.id)
                        commentsData.commentTxt = ""}) {
                    Text("Comment")
                        .fontWeight(.bold)
                        .foregroundColor(.white)
                        .padding(.vertical,5)
                        .padding(.horizontal,15)
                        .background(Color("blue"))
                        .clipShape(Capsule())
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .background(Color.white.opacity(0.06))
            .cornerRadius(5)
            .preferredColorScheme(.dark)

if commentsData.comments.isEmpty{
                
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
                
                if commentsData.noComments{
                    Text("No Comments")
                    
                }
                else{
                    ProgressView()
                }
                Spacer(minLength: 0)
            }
            else{
                ScrollView{
                    VStack(spacing: 15){
                        
                        ForEach(commentsData.comments){comment in
                            
                            CommentsRow(post: post, comment: comment, commentData: commentsData)
                            
                        }
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .padding(.bottom,55)
                }
            }
            
            
        }
        .onAppear {
          commentsData.post = post
        }
```

*CommentsViewModel.swift*

```
class CommentsViewModel : ObservableObject{
    
    @Published var comments: [CommentsModel] = []
    @Published var noComments = false
    @Published var newComment = false
    @Published var commentTxt = ""

    let ref = Firestore.firestore()
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid

    var post: PostModel? {
        didSet{
            if let post = self.post {
                getComments(id: post.id)
            }
        }
    }

    func getComments(id: String) {
        print("ID from getComments is: \(id)")
        ref.collection("Posts").document(id).collection("Comments").addSnapshotListener { (snap, err) in
            
        guard let docs = snap else{
            self.noComments = true
            return
            }
            
            if docs.documentChanges.isEmpty{
                self.noComments = true
                return
            }
            
            docs.documentChanges.forEach { (doc) in
                
                //Checking if doc added
                
                if doc.type == .added{
                    
                    let title = doc.document.data()["title"] as! String
                    let time = doc.document.data()["time"] as! Timestamp
                    let userRef = doc.document.data()["ref"] as! DocumentReference
                    
                fetchUser(uid: userRef.documentID) { (user) in
                    
                    self.comments.append(CommentsModel(id: doc.document.documentID, title: title, time: time.dateValue(), user: user))
                    
                    self.comments.sort { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                        return p1.time > p2.time
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
                if doc.type == .removed{
                    
                    let id = doc.document.documentID
                    
                    self.comments.removeAll { (comment) -> Bool in
                        return comment.id == id
                    }
                }
                
                if doc.type == .modified{
                    
                    print("Updated...")
                    
                    let id = doc.document.documentID
                    let title = doc.document.data()["title"] as! String
                    
                    let index = self.comments.firstIndex { (comment) -> Bool in
                        return comment.id == id
                    } ?? -1
                    
                    if index != -1{
                        self.comments[index].title = title
                    }
                }
        }
    }
}
func comment(id: String){
        //posting data
            
            let newDocRef = ref.collection("Posts").document(id).collection("Comments").document()
            newDocRef.setData([
                "title" : self.commentTxt,
                "ref": ref.collection("Users").document(self.uid),
                "time": Date(),
            ]){ (err) in
                
                if err != nil{
                    return
                }
            }
    }
}
```

*PostRow.swift*

```
var commentsData = CommentsViewModel()
@State private var showingComments = false
```

```
Button(action: {
                    commentsData.comments.removeAll()
                    showingComments = true
                }){
                    Text("Comments")
                }
                .transition(.move(edge: .leading))
                .sheet(isPresented: self.$showingComments)
                {
                    CommentsView(commentsData: commentsData, post: post)
                }
```

*CommentsModel.swift / PostModel.swift*

```
struct CommentsModel : Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var time: Date
    var user: UserModel
}
struct PostModel : Identifiable {
    
    var id: String
    //other vars unrelated to this
}
```

If any more code is needed, please let me know and I will provide it. Any help/suggestions will help.

10/15/2021 - Months later, I still have not figured this out. Anyone who can help, it would be greatly appriciated!

Comment: In your GIF, you show a "Comment" button -- that doesn't seem to appear anywhere in your code, so it's pretty hard to know what's happening when that button is pressed.

Comment: Totally forgot about that part. I've added it to the code block under "CommentsView.swift". Let me know if theres any other code you need.

Comment: Maybe there's a way to refresh my ScrollView? I think that would fix it, but I'm not sure how.

Comment: It is very difficult to diagnose this without a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). We really need working code that does what your gif dhows. That doesn't mean posting all of your code. What it means is you need the essence of the code that runs this part of the UI.

Comment: You're still not showing the what happens when that button is pressed. My suspicion is that it has to do with your snapshotListener and ending up with multiple copies being appended to the end of the array.

Comment: I assume there is a race condition when you're assigning the mapped documents to the published property in the for loop. I'd recommend not doing this. Instead, use map or compactMap to perform the mapping (and, - please - do yourself a favour and use Codable: https://peterfriese.dev/firestore-codable-the-comprehensive-guide/). Then, assign the mapped documents once you have finished *all* the documents.

Comment: What am I missing from my comments button code? I think I put it all there..

Comment: You call a function called comment that I can’t find in your code.

Comment: Are you referring to 'commentsData.comments.removeAll()'? If so they is defined here in CommentsViewModel: '@Published var comments: [CommentsModel] = []' if that's not what you're referring to please let me know because I really think I've included every part of the comment system

Comment: In your button action you call `commentsData.comment(id: post.id)`. The function `comment` is not shown.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not realize thats what you were referring to. I've went ahead and added the function in CommentsViewModel. Let me know if theres anything else.

Comment: Post a [mre]. What you have here is too difficult to piecemeal together. Make it copy and pastable into Xcode.

Comment: What other parts of the code do you need?

Comment: Did you read the [mre] link? Make something easily copy and pastable into Xcode.